# Returning multiple array values from loop

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop, return

I have an activity in my app that takes a searchword and returns file names that contain that search term.  I am trying to modify this code so that it can split a search term and show files that contain any of the search terms.  For instance if the search term is "big dog" it will return files that have "big" in the title and also files that contain "dog" in the title.

The part of the code is:

```
 if (f.isDirectory()){ 

         return true; // Don't discard any subdirectories  
                           }

           else {  


               String delimiter = " +";  /* delimiter */  
               searchname.searchname = searchname.searchname.toUpperCase();  

               //Split the search string
                String [] tempname = searchname.searchname.split(delimiter); 
                 //Array for the file names to be stored
                boolean[] namestring = new boolean[tempname.length];
               //Counter
                int count;
               count = 0;

              for(int i=0; i<tempname.length; i++)
                  {   
                  //While i is less than tempname size store filename to namestring array
                    namestring[i] = name.toUpperCase().contains(tempname[i]);
                    //Add one to count
                    count = +1;
                    //Once count = tempname length you can return all of the array values
                     if (count == tempname.length){
                      return namestring[i];
                     }           
                                        }

                  }  
return false;
```

My java is pretty basic and I might be missing something very obvious.

Thank you very much for your help

---

Thank you all for your very fast replies.

I think I understand what you are all saying.  I have amended my code to show:

```
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {  

           File f = new File(dir, name); // Form the file path "dir/name". 

           String delimiter = " ";  /* delimiter */  
           searchname.searchname = searchname.searchname.toUpperCase(); 

                 //Split the search string//
            String [] tempname = searchname.searchname.split(delimiter); 

            //Array of Booleans         
           ArrayList<Boolean> matches = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

           if (f.isDirectory()){ 

         return true; // Don't discard any subdirectories  
                           }

           else {  


              for(int i=0; i<tempname.length; i++)
                  {   

                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (tempname[i]), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  matches.add(name.toUpperCase().contains(tempname[i]));
                            }

                  }

           return matches;  

    }});
```

However in Eclipse it shows "return matches;" as an error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to boolean".  If I make the suggested changes it puts errors on the "public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {" part.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `searchname.searchname` what were you thinking when you put names to variables?

Comment: This will never return `nameString[i]` because `count == tempname.length` will never be true inside a `for-loop` that checks for `i<tempname.length`. `count` and `i` are incremented during/after every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function should returns boolean by its definition:
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
but you return ArrayList.

This is probably what you want:

```
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {  
    File f = new File(dir, name); // Form the file path "dir/name". 
    String delimiter = " ";  /* delimiter */  
    searchname.searchname = searchname.searchname.toUpperCase(); 

    //Split the search string//
    String [] tempname = searchname.searchname.split(delimiter); 

    if (f.isDirectory()){
        return true; // Don't discard any subdirectories  
    } else {  
        for(int i=0; i<tempname.length; i++){   
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (tempname[i]), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(name.toUpperCase().contains(tempname[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }               
    }

    return false;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much JackyZhu!  I really appreciate all of your help.  It has led me to research loops and booleans more and I have learnt a great deal from your insight. Just so you know, this final piece of tweaked code works perfectly :-)

Answer (score 4):

well one thing that you missed is

```
count = +1;
```

in your for loop. It should be

```
cout++;
```

or

```
cout = count+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `return namestring[i]` is only returning one value (and as mentioned will not be reached). To return all the array values you need Declare the method as returning an array and then just return the array `namestring` i.e

```
public boolean[] yourMethod()
{
     boolean[] namestring = ....
     //Your code
     return namestring;
}
```

I think you should use a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) for your return type, In your method implement an [`Arraylist`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of Strings (or booleans if you wish). The advantage of this is that you will have a dynamic size available i.e if your search term is `"Big dog"` and you have 20 files and 5 of them match, the array you create only has 2 elements so will only return two of the filenames. If you do it as a List it will grow dynamically as you add more.

To Inistialise:

```
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then when you find a match in your loop (pseudo code):

```
 //For each file name
     // For each search term
         // If name contains search term
              // Add to list
               matches.add(name)   // Actual code to add to list.
```

Then return the list

```
return matches;
```

Answer (score 0):

comments:

1. count = +1 should be count +=1
2. if you want to return after for loop ends, you don't need count, just put the return sentence outside for loop
3. you want to return array as in your comments, but you only return one Boolean value and always the last one
4. it seems you don't need to return array as you only need to determine whether the file name contains any of the term, you can just return true when any of the split array is contained by the file name.
5. your code uses " +" as delimiter, but you mentioned "big dog" as example whose delimiter is " "
6. try to troubleshoot with this debugging or logging to analyze which part doesn't work as you expect

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I have amended my code (See above).  I still get an error though as there is a problem returning the values from the array.  I do need to return the array values as it is these filenames that get listed on screen